# geckodriver 0.15 does not work with Firefox 64-bit

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using selenium Grid to run tests over windows virtual machines.

After updating to:

1. geckodriver - v0.15
2. selenium-server-standalone.jar - v3.3.1
3. selenium webdriver - v3.3

My tests do not work on 64-bit version of Firefox (v52). I get following exception:

`Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit JRE ? Also, check if FF is installed on the server machine.

Comment: I am using 64bit JRE, but I am using 32 bit geckodriver. FF is installed on server machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing 32-bit geckodriver with 64-bit version worked for me.

Another solution is to add the Firefox folder under Environment variable `Path`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with 32-bit GeckoDriver. I was able to solve this by providing Firefox location using FirefoxOptions class with GeckoDriver 0.15.0 and Selenium 3.3.1 -

```
    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

more info here - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: I am using a grid. Is there a way to provide binary location on node configuration file?

Comment: Hi.. Sorry, I have not used Grid so I'm not sure of the process for that